# File.delete() does not trigger WatchService

Tags: java, file, groovy, delete-file, watchservice

I created a Java program which observes a directory for changes using a `WatchService`.

Everything was working as expected but today I did some cleanup with a Groovy script using `file.delete()` and noticed that this did not trigger the `WatchService`.

This is how my `WatchService` is initialized and registered:

```
WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

Path dir = Paths.get(src.getAbsolutePath());
dir.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);
```

Any ideas why the delete via script did not trigger the `WatchService`?

Comment: Have you tried checking `StandardWatchEventKinds.OVERFLOW` for missed events? And verifying that the script **does** actually delete a file, i.e. that it completes?

Comment: Do you check the _return code_ of the `delete` operation? Also, can't groovy just use JSR 203 instead of `File`? You [shouldn't be using `File`](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks) anyway. Not in 2016.

Comment: @fge OP isn't saying the code snippet shown in the question is Groovy, only that they tried deleting a file with Groovy. I suspect Groovy is out of the equation, unless their script actually didn't work.

Comment: @Mena a "Groovy script using `file.delete()`" seems quite clear to me

Comment: @fge I can't read XD

Comment: This might be related, but it's impossible to tell because you didn't post a [complete, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581845/watcher-stops-after-changeT